# Python interpreter output to variable

Tags: python

So in python we have the interpreter spitting out evaluations
of the last expression.

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
```

So my question is "Is the output (3) kept in a variable, and if yes, how do I access it?"

Comment: Try `_` and enter.

Comment: why not just assign the expression to a variable to begin with?

Comment: If you put it as an answer i will accept it, thank you @pistol2myhead

Comment: _ returns only the last value. Why wouldn't you assign a variable name to it?

Comment: Well, it's to use for my calculator script, I was getting tired of writing down the output of the last expression / pressing up and editing. Pressing up works but it ends up being a very long formula sometimes.

Comment: @Caveman you can also use `__` (double underscore) or `___` (tripple underscore) to refer to the output of the second to last expression and third to last output respectively.

Comment: @bagljas I tried it, it didn't work by default in python 2.7.15

Comment: @Caveman sorry, my bad, it seems that this is the feature of the IPython interpreter. I forgot to test it in plain python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access it like this:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> _
3
>>>
```

`_` will keep result of last expression.

Comment: ..until reassigned

Comment: Technically everything in `python` is "until reassigned" (lol)